# Adding attribute on html element inside the iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have this code for getting the attributes of an html element inside an `iframe`.

**Code:**

```
$("#frameID").contents().find("#htmlelementID").attr("myattr");
```

My dilemma here is i want to add a new attribute on the html element inside my iframe.

I'll truly appreciate every idea that will help me on this.

Comment: Note that adding a proprietary attribute will make the HTML invalid. You should use a `data-*` attribute for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Use the setter version of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

```
$("#frameID").contents().find("#htmlelementID").attr("newattr",  'newvalue');
```

Answer (score 0):

by [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
$("#frameID").contents().find("#htmlelementID").attr("attrname",  'atrvalue');
```

by [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop)

```
$("#frameID").contents().find("#htmlelementID").prop("attrname",  'atrvalue');
```